# CakePHP - How to format the message into sentences

Tags: cakephp, flash-message

I am using CakePHP 2.8.9 and my app receives Flash messages.
How to format the message into sentences. For example: MSG1 new line MSG2 and so on.

```
$message = 'Bla bla bla .new line bla bla bla';
$this->Flash->set($message, array(
                'element' => 'flash_error',
            ));
```

I already tried with `br nbsp /n`.

```
$message = "Bla bla bla < br/> line bla bla bla";
$message = "Bla bla bla /n line bla bla bla";
$message = "Bla bla bla &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; line bla bla bla";
```

What should I use to create a new line ?

Comment: since is html `<br>` should work

Comment: Check the manual how to edit strings. What you want is called a **linebreak**. Then render the html as `Bla bla bla </br> bla bla bla`

Comment: I  already tried with br nbsp /n

Comment: @user3616375 it might be worth showing the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: `< br/>` isn't valid HTML, whitespace after the opening bracket is not allowed. Also escaped character sequences are indicated using a backslash, not a forward slash (not that they would work here anyways), and `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space, not a linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is not related to CakePhp flash render, it's related with a Security Component callback error method where I want to flash message. Ended it up using something like : 
`__('admin', 'Security error occured.%s Please, try    again.','&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;');`